# MySQL query result: What does the time shown mean?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I am running some MySQL queries from a shell. At the end of the query result, MySQL prints the total number of rows in the result and a time duration.

```
mysql>select * from mytable;
[Query result here]
1000000 rows in set (1.50 sec)
```

What does the **1.50 sec** mean? From my trials, I understood it is not the total query duration. Is it the query processing time within the database engine? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a period of time between [start_timer](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L3521) and `mysql_end_timer` calls within a function that executes your query. As I understand, it is the time spent on the preparation of the result set on the server side, before you started to fetch the result set from the server.

There is a similar question and the answer with links on the neighbor site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72076/16185.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! I tried googling but the other link didn't show up.